# Agregar documentos por defecto en mongodb utilizando mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

les queria consultar sobre como agregar documentos por default a una base de datos en mongodb utilizando mongoose. Estuve investigando y no puedo encontrar una documentacion que me ayude. Desde ya gracias.

Code:

```
var { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");

var LibroSchema = Schema({
  isbn: String,
  titulo: String,
  autor: String,
  editorial: String,
  stock: Number,
  imagen: String,
});

module.exports = model("Libro", LibroSchema);
```

Comment: Por favor, el código debe or como texto y no en imagen. Por otro lado, ¿A qué te refieres con *documentos por default* ? Por lo que entiendo quieres hacer un [*database seeding*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_seeding), para lo cual tienes muchas opciones, desde escribir tu propio generador de datos aleatorios o usar alguno ya escrito. ¿Podrías aclarar tu pregunta? Saludos

Comment: vi lo de database seeding y es lo que busco realizar, es decir iniciar una base de datos de mongo db con documentos iniciales. Por lo que busco como realizarlo en  mongoose.